# Installing app with android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES permission and root

Tags: android, apk, packageinstaller

This is just a POC app that I am creating to try something but I have an older rooted device and trying to create an installer app that can manage other apps on the device by itself. I added the permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES"/>
```

to my manifest

Using [this](https://commonsware.com/Q/pages/chap-pkg-001.html) PackageInstaller example I am getting a dummy apk file I have on the device and trying to install it

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    try{
        val apk = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sample_app.apk")
        Log.d("MainActivity", "Path: ${apk.path}")

        val params = PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL)
        params.setAppPackageName(packageName)

        val sessionId = packageManager.packageInstaller.createSession(params)
        val session = packageManager.packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId)

        apk.inputStream().use { apkStream->
            session.openWrite("apk-install", 0, apk.length()).use {sessionStream ->
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Copying")
                apkStream.copyTo(sessionStream)

                Log.d("MainActivity", "Sync")
                session.fsync(sessionStream)
            }
        }

        val intent = Intent(this, InstallReceiver::class.java)
        val pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this,
            RootInstallService::class.hashCode(),
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )

        Log.d("MainActivity", "Commit")
        session.commit(pi.intentSender)
        session.close()
    }catch (e: Exception){
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

}
```

I ran the app to install it on the device, copied the `base.apk` and `lib` folder from `data/app/` to a folder in `system/priv-app`. Deleted the app from `data/app` and rebooted the device.

Opening the app once rebooted it runs without error but the app does not appear in the launcher.

Yes I am aware I can install with using adb commands in the app but I don't want to do this, I am looking for a native sdk solution.

I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: What you describe sounds more like a system app than a root app as you the title indicates.

Comment: As I understand it you are able to copy an app to the system/priv-app folder and it becomes a system app where those permissions are granted hence needing root to be able to do that

Comment: Yes, but that is how you install the management app you develop. This is unrelated how the app itself manages the other apps, thus I find it very confusing to first talk about root but then describe a system app that has the permission to (un)install other apps.

Comment: @Robert Again this is just a POC app, I dont have system signing keys so therefore you need root to be able to move the app to the system folder so it is relevant. If I were not to put that I have a rooted device in the question I would just get people telling me you would need root to do this without being a system app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was setting the app package name to my app

```
params.setAppPackageName(packageName)
```

which according to the docs says that is that if the app package does not match the app being installed it will fail so I just removed that line and it started working